# Куки, Сессия, ЛокалСторадж - но между браузерами

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, интернет-магазин

Рекламирую свой сайт через интсаграм (к примеру). При клике на мою ссылку, пользователю открывается встроенный в инсту браузер, в этом браузере юзер может воспользоваться корзиной без авторизации/регистрации.

Товары его я могу сохранить в Куки/Сессию/ЛС, но стоит пользователю зайти не через встроенный в инсту браузер, а через свой (хром например), корзина конечно же будет пустой

Подскажите, возможен ли обход ситуации? Как сделать чтобы данные сохранялись?

Работаю в связке php/js/mySQL

Comment: а зачем он перезаходит через вторйо браузер?

Comment: @Jean-Claude как минимум, потому что есть таая возможность! Чел может накидать в корзину, потом отвлечься и зайти на сайт позже. Только вот зайдет он уже со своего браузера. В этом случае слетят UTM метки

Comment: Локалсторадж сидит внутри конкретного браузера, сессия - (условно) внутри вкладки одного конкретного браузера (либо нескольких вкладках, открытых одновременно, но опять же в одном браузере). Так что эти варианты точно никак не помогут. Куки это хоть и файлы, но один браузер может не знать, где другой хранит куки. При установке нового браузера обычно даже есть вопрос - испортировать ли личные данные, но это по сути ручной импорт. Так что именно с этими вариантами решения, лично я не вижу.

Comment: Опять же, судя по вопросу, вы хотите, чтоб все это происходило вне ведома пользователя (без доп.вопросов, импортов, экспортов данных и т.п.). Непонятно насколько это корректно. Я тут вижу явный вариант - дать возможность пользователю выгрузить корзину в файл, если он хочет восстановить ее в другом браузере. Соответственно дать возможность импорта такого файла в самой корзине

Comment: Ну а уж как именно сохранять данные Вы будете в коде решать сами, можете туда и метки записать до кучи

Comment: достаточно в ссылку добавить id сессии на сервере, в которой и хранить все данные. тогда открыв конкретную ссылку можно увидеть все набранное

Comment: @Grundy, хороший вариант, прям нравится!Нужно проврить, насколько решит это мой вопрос!